# How to access and modify a text file in github from an express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, github

I have made an express local server. I am getting some data in an HTML form and after making some validations, I am appending the data into a text file. My project folder contains all the javascript, server, HTML, and CSS files.

My requirement is as follows: The text file into which the data will be appended every time the form is filled will reside in Github. How can I append the form data into the text file on GitHub?
Also, this project will be hosted on WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try tried [this demonstration](https://gist.github.com/getify/f5b111381413f9d9f4b2571c7d5822ce) ?
It requires [nodegit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit) and a GitHub Access Token (you can create one [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens))

the only other thing you'll need is the authentication callback for github:

```js
const authCallbacks = {
    certificateCheck: () => 1,
    credentials: () => git.Cred.userpassPlaintextNew(TOKEN,  "x-oauth-basic")
}
```

Comment: Hey I guess you wanted to insert links into your answer but I guess links haven't been added.